# clickhouse distributed query on each shard

Tags: clickhouse

We have a CK cluster with four nodes, this cluster has two shards and each shard has two replicas.
There are two distributed tables, both tables are replicated, and we have another table created by mysql engine.

Now we want to insert join result of distributed_a and table_mysql into distributed_b, SQL like this:

```
insert into distributed_b select sum(t1.click), t1.user_id from distributed_a t1 left join table_mysql t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id group by t1.user_id
```

Data with the same user_id can be guaranteed to be on the same shard, and table_mysql data comes from mysql, so the data of each shard join is the same

So my question, is there a way to make query execute on local shard, just like insert local on each shard

```
insert into local_b select sum(t1.click), t1.user_id from local_a t1 left join table_mysql t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id group by t1.user_id
```

Or i can run local insert on each shard by myself ,but it makes the case complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this setting

```
M(UInt64, parallel_distributed_insert_select, 0, "Process distributed INSERT SELECT query in the same cluster on local tables on every shard; if set to 1 - SELECT is executed on each shard; if set to 2 - SELECT and INSERT are executed on each shard", 0)
```

Requires testing.